# How to Create an Entity for Deleted Files

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I've been working on an ER diagram and now I want to add an entity which will keep the records of the deleted data. I have an entity called User and as a weak entity of it, I made a relationship as One to One. What I think is that for each user record there is going to be one delete record since they are unique. Yet, I still have some difficulties in order to make the relation. As I mentioned I created it as a weak entity but I'm not sure whether it's true or not. How can I create an entity which keeps the deleted records of another entity?

Comment: If I understood well. You have two tables. User and UserDeleted. The record Will only existe at one of tem?

Answer (score 0):

Is the record going to exist in only one table?
For ex: once deleted, the user will only be on deleted table.

If so, you dont have relation at all.

In this case, logical delete would be a better approach.
Just create a column "isDeleted". It will demand the applications tô validate If a user is deleted before using its data, but will prevent
unnecessary tables.